# Could not preview file after uploading in google drive by google drive api php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have used the google drive API to upload files to google drive. The files are being created successfully but they are not opening in google drive, no preview and when I open the file, it says
" could not preview file, You may be offline or with limited connectivity. Try downloading instead.
"
why does this happen?
when I download the file it gives the blank documents.
I am uploading pdf and doc files
how can I solve this issue?

the function that is used to insert the files

```
function insert_file_to_drive( $file_path, $file_name, $parent_file_id = null ){
    $service = new Google_Service_Drive( $GLOBALS['client'] );
    $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

    $file->setName( $file_name );

    if( !empty( $parent_file_id ) ){
        $file->setParents( [ $parent_file_id ] );        
    }

    $result = $service->files->create(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
            'uploadType' => 'media',
        )
    );

    $is_success = false;
    
    if( isset( $result['name'] ) && !empty( $result['name'] ) ){
        $is_success = true;
    }

    return $is_success;
}
```

I have done the coding using this site
[PHP google drive API file upload](https://thecodelearners.com/php-google-drive-api-list-create-folders-sub-folders-and-upload-files/)

Comment: What kind of files are we talking about? Can you download them anyway? Google drive, for sure, does not support preview for every type of file out there.

Comment: Are you sure this happens only to files uploaded through API? Try uploading a file using their platform and see if it gives you the same error. Try using google drive in a different browser or on an app. Clear cache. The issue is most likely not related to API, but possibly.

Comment: the files are doc and pdf and I also could not download then as it gives the blank page

Comment: This can be anything and without reference code it's impossible to help you out. Do a search here in SO (cases like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451948/google-drive-php-api-empty-uploaded-file) might be relevant to your particular issue).

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @nitrin0 my code is exactly the same as I have mentioned in the link

Comment: Files will only open in Google drive if they are google type files,   google docs, google sheets ..... when you upload those types of files you need to ensure that you are sending the propler MimeType in  order for example a excel file to be converted to a google sheet.   With out seeing a [example] its hard to help you.

Comment: I have added the code of uploading

Comment: what does $result->id say?

Comment: @DaImTo it returns the id (from the google drive) of the file uploaded

Comment: The problem is that the file uploaded becomes empty.

Comment: Have you verified if the `$file_path` is correct? and if the file being uploaded is <5MB?

Comment: file is not less than 5 MB but I have read that for files more than 5 mb we have to use the ```uploadType=>'resumeable'``` but even doing this makes no difference

Comment: and even for the files less than 5 mb it is not working

Comment: How about your `$file_path` have you verified it is correct? have you also tried setting the mimetype in your file resource object `$file->setMimeType()` and see if it will resolve the issue?

Comment: @SAIra define empty.   does it have a size or can you just not open it in the Web app

Comment: I did tried ```mineType=mime_content_type()```, the file get opened but it has a single blank page, nothing else

Comment: Please try setting the mimetype using `$file->setMimeType()` and with `mineType=mime_content_type()` .You can try using either resumable upload or multipart upload based on the size of the file being uploaded. You could also try disabling your antivirus/firewall in the meantime when you try to run your code and see what happens

Comment: @RonM i tried this but still same result, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wrF0t2sSfAB4sAz7nDIgCysOti-wcJs7/view?usp=sharing see this is how the file is being stored

Comment: Hi you can file this as a bug in https://issuetracker.google.com/